# how to bind a class to a parent of an input checked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, vue.js

I have three selectable input options in my html. I apply a class to them at the moment they are selected and at the parent hover.
I would like to keep the style of the parent in the hover event the same as when selecting the input but from what I see in other posts there is no way to apply a class to the parent of an input checked.
I'm trying with js to apply a class to each parent depending on the selected input, but I manage to apply it the first time I click, but as soon as I select another option the parent of the previous one is not deactivated.
This is my html

```
        <div class="resume-icons">
            <div class="resume-column" v-bind:class="{ paymentIsActive: paymentIsSelected }">
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="selectedResume" value="payment" v-model="selectedResume" checked @change="onChange($event)">
                  <i class="icon-credit-card"></i>
              </label>
              <p class="resume-subtitle">Validated</p>                
            </div>
            <div class="resume-column" v-bind:class="{ supportIsActive: supportIsSelected }">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="selectedResume" value="support" v-model="selectedResume" checked @change="onChange($event)">
                <i class="icon-support"></i>
              </label>
              <p class="resume-subtitle">Support</p>                
            </div>
            <div class="resume-column" id="call" v-bind:class="{ callIsActive: callIsSelected }">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="selectedResume" value="call" v-model="selectedResume" checked @change="onChange($event)">
                <i class="icon-phone-3"></i>
              </label>
              <p class="resume-subtitle">Call</p>               
            </div>
        </div>
```

here´s mu script

```
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                
                selectedResume: null,
                paymentSelected: false,
                callIsSelected: false,
                supportIsSelected: false,
                paymentIsSelected: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
          submitted() {
              this.isSubmitted = true;
          },
          navigateToService(){
            this.$store.dispatch('setStep', this.step + 1)
            this.$router.push('/devis/service')
          },
          onChange(event) {
              if (event.target.value === 'call') {
                  return this.callIsSelected = true;
                  return this.supportIsSelected = false;
                  return this.paymentIsSelected = false;
                  return this.paymentSelected = true;
                  this.navigateToService();
              }
              if (event.target.value === 'support') {
                  
                  return this.supportIsSelected = true;
                  return this.callIsSelected = false;
                  return this.paymentIsSelected = false;
                  return this.paymentSelected = true;
                  this.navigateToService();
              },
               if (event.target.value === 'payment') {
                  return this.paymentIsSelected = true;
                  return this.supportIsSelected = flase;
                  return this.callIsSelected = false;
                  return this.paymentSelected = true;
                  this.navigateToService();
              }

          }
        },
        computed: {
            
        },
        components: {

        }
    }
```

and here my css

```
.callIsActive {
    background-color: #D53865;
}

.callIsActive p {
    color: #ffff;
}

.supportIsActive {
    background-color: #D53865;
}

.supportIsActive p {
    color: #ffff;
}

.paymentIsActive {
    background-color: #D53865;
}

.paymentIsActive p {
    color: #ffff;
}
```

I don't see why when you enter one of the other if statement in the 'onChange' method you don't deactivate the previous classes.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 onChange(event) {
              if (event.target.value === 'call') {
                  return this.callIsSelected = true;
                  return this.supportIsSelected = false;
                  return this.paymentIsSelected = false;
                  return this.paymentSelected = true;
                  this.navigateToService();
              }
              if (event.target.value === 'support') {
                  
                  return this.supportIsSelected = true;
                  return this.callIsSelected = false;
                  return this.paymentIsSelected = false;
                  return this.paymentSelected = true;
                  this.navigateToService();
              },
               if (event.target.value === 'payment') {
                  return this.paymentIsSelected = true;
                  return this.supportIsSelected = flase;
                  return this.callIsSelected = false;
                  return this.paymentSelected = true;
                  this.navigateToService();
              }

          }
```

You are not supposed to put `return` there, that makes all code after the first return isn't executed, change your `onChange` method to:

```js
onChange(event) {
      if (event.target.value === "call") {
        this.callIsSelected = true;
        this.supportIsSelected = false;
        this.paymentIsSelected = false;
        this.paymentSelected = true;
        this.navigateToService();
      }
      if (event.target.value === "support") {
        this.supportIsSelected = true;
        this.callIsSelected = false;
        this.paymentIsSelected = false;
        this.paymentSelected = true;
        this.navigateToService();
      }
      if (event.target.value === "payment") {
        this.paymentIsSelected = true;
        this.supportIsSelected = false;
        this.callIsSelected = false;
        this.paymentSelected = true;
        this.navigateToService();
      }
    }
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-heisenberg-dt701?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been programming for a short time and I didn't realize that I can't return multiple values anymore!